# How to make an image path show up on a JPanel in Java?

Tags: java, image, jpanel

I have been going through the code but my image is the only thing that has not been showing up for my final project. I can not seem to find out what the problem is. I have put the image path on my flash drive and my desktop but it does not seem to work. Please see what you can do. Thank you! Below is the complete code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class LatinLife extends JPanel{

    public LatinLife() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        Test Bub = new Test();
        //maybe make the file a picture instead of a text file


        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/hh.jpg");
        JComponent panel1 = makeImagePanel("Latin Life Saver");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Home", icon, panel1,
                "Does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.white);

        JComponent panel2 = makeImagePanel("/Users/ashleyvpalermo/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-05-31 at 3.33.25 PM.png");
        ImageIcon acon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/Smiling_Face_Emoji_large.png");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Cum Clauses", acon, panel2,
                "Does nothing");
        JLabel nice = new JLabel("Cum Clauses");
        nice.setIcon(acon);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_2);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.yellow);


        JComponent panel3 = makeImagePanel("Ut clauses");
        ImageIcon bcon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/images-1.jpeg");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Ut Clauses", bcon, panel3,
                "Ut Clauses");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_3);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.pink);

        JComponent panel4 = makeImagePanel("Vocab");
        ImageIcon ccon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/images.jpeg");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Vocab", ccon, panel4,
                "Still does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_4);
        panel4.setBackground(Color.white);

        JComponent panel5 = makeImagePanel("Ablatives");
        ImageIcon jcon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/Unknown-1.jpeg");
        panel5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 50));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Ablatives", jcon, panel5,
                "Does nothing at all");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_5);
        panel5.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        JComponent panel6 = makeImagePanel("Culture");
        ImageIcon kcon = createImageIcon("/Volumes/APCOMSCI/Unknown.jpeg");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Culture", kcon, panel6,
                "Still does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_6);
        panel6.setBackground(Color.pink);

         //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
    add(tabbedPane);
        //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    }

    protected JComponent makeImagePanel(String path) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(path);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        //        java.net.URL imgURL = NewJApplet.class.getResource(path);

        try {
            java.net.URL imgURL = (new File(path)).toURL();
            if (imgURL != null) {
                return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from
     * the event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Latin Life Saver");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new LatinLife(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();

            }
        });

    }

    public class Test {
        public Test() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img = null;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/Users/ashleyvpalermo/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-05-31 at 3.33.25 PM.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (img != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
}
```

I am having difficulty with this part because I originally had it work as text but now i want to put a picture inside the frame. How would I do it?

```
        JComponent panel2 = makeImagePanel("/Users/ashleyvpalermo/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-05-31 at 3.33.25 PM.png");
```

Comment: As a personal preference, you should consider using `ImageIO.read` over `ImageIcon`, as `ImageIO` will throw an exception when the image can't be loaded

Comment: `TabbedPaneDemo.class.getResource(path)` assumes that the resource is locatable by prefixing the class-path elements to it, this is unlikely the case.  You can place the image within your applications context (ie the Jar file) and use the path from root of your project to it instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Embedding the image/resource? It will depend on your IDE/build process. Most IDEs allow you to drop resources into their `src` folder and they will automatically be included in the Jar

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok say I wanted to switch it from a image file to like a txt file what would I have to use?

Comment: It depends. Do you want the resource embedded in your Jar file (which makes it readonly) or do you want to read it from the disk (externally)

Comment: @MadProgrammer it would be a resource embedded in my jar file

Comment: Well, getting into you project is the same. Loading it would follow either [`Class#getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [`Class#getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a short test app to try this, and just put in this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/Volumes/APCOMSCI/second_ed_sourcecode-2/APCS Final Project Latin Life Saver/Cum_Clauses_Pic.jpg");
```

(with a local file which was also a jpg)

And it worked.

I thought the spaces in the address might have been an issue, but mine was fine.

(I was accessing a jpg on the desktop so I put it in a new folder called 'New folder' and it worked fine, despite the space)

Loading it from a resource URL would normally be if you wanted to jar it up or something, and then the address of the image will be relative (e.g. you'd expect it to normally be packaged in the jar as well)

---

If you want to use a URL you can try this:

```
        java.net.URL imgURL = (new File(path)).toURL();
```

(also you need to catch a MalformedURLException)

```
protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
//        java.net.URL imgURL = NewJApplet.class.getResource(path);

  try {
    java.net.URL imgURL = (new File(path)).toURL();
    if (imgURL != null) {
      return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
      System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
    }
  } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
  return null;
}
```

But your IDE should complain that it is deprecated - the javadoc suggests converting it to a URI first

E.g.

```
        java.net.URL imgURL = (new File(path)).toURI().toURL();
```

So why go through File?  The reason is that (if you separate it out as its own variable) you can call useful methods such as .exists();

e.g.

```
        File f = new File(path);
        if (f.exists()) {
            java.net.URL imgURL = f.toURI().toURL();
```

(etc)

Comment: so all the information in my file is what is confusing the program? @rick

Comment: @AvPalermo_10: While Rick means well, follow MadProgrammer's lead as it bests this answer by far. User resources, not files for one.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok Thank You!

Comment: Loading it from a resource URL would normally be if you wanted to jar it up or something, and then the address of the image will be relative (e.g. you'd expect it to normally be packaged in the jar as well

Comment: Are you using an IDE?  It should be telling you which classes it needs.

My little test app I had to import:

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

Comment: @Rick I figured it out... Just how would I make the JComponent distribute my text?

Comment: @Rick I want to have it sort of look like this but I don't know how to get the packages that it comes with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html